# Sum row values based on start and date of a month in another column

Tags: vba, excel

Attaching image for better understanding of question:

[image]

Here, Column A has dates, B has daily amount and C has the cumulative sum of each days.

I want to stop the cumulative calculation at end of each month based on A column and start recalculating for next month. Just like shown in image.

I am using below code to find the end of month and on first day of month assigning B=C, But confused how can I start calculating cumulative amount from next day onward for that month.

Appreciate if someone provide me a logic to achieve this.

```
Sub MonthInt()

    Dim MaxGain As Workbook
    Dim DailyData As Worksheet
    Dim n As Long, J As Long

    Set MaxGain = Excel.Workbooks("MaxGain.xlsm")
    Set DailyData = MaxGain.Worksheets("DailyData")


   n = DailyData.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row


   DailyData.Range("B2") = DailyData.Range("C2")

   For J = 3 To n

   If DailyData.Range("A" & J) = Application.WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(DailyData.Range("A" & J), 0) Then

   DailyData.Range("C" & J + 1) = DailyData.Range("B" & J)


   End If

    Next
   End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you need VBA to get the desired output?

You may use the formulas to achieve the desired output.

Try this...

In C2

```
=B2
```

In C3

```
=IF(MONTH(A3)<>MONTH(A2),B3,C2+B3)
```

and copy it down.

**Edit:**

If you want to implement the formula through VBA, you may try something like this...

```
Sub MonthInt()
    Dim MaxGain As Workbook
    Dim DailyData As Worksheet
    Dim n As Long

    Set MaxGain = Excel.Workbooks("MaxGain.xlsm")
    Set DailyData = MaxGain.Worksheets("DailyData")

    n = DailyData.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    With DailyData
        .Range("C2").Value = .Range("B2").Value
        .Range("C3:C" & n).Formula = "=IF(MONTH(A3)<>MONTH(A2),B3,C2+B3)"
        .Range("C3:C" & n).Value = .Range("C3:C" & n).Value
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: I may have more than 200 months of data and this will change for each run. So prefer to use VBA rather than adding formula

Comment: I am marking this answer. I was able to convert this into a VBA script and looped through all rows.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply as I was away from the system. Well in that case, to implement the formula through VBA, you don't need to loop through the cells. You can apply the formula in column C at once.

Comment: I have edited the solution and added the VBA code to implement the formula in column C. See if that helps.